# error when inserting point value in point column for Geo coordinates

Tags: mysql

I'm having a point column and now i wan't them to populate it with point value which is calculated with `GeomFromText(POINT(45.713958 14.209463))`. How ever i'm keep getting this error and i don't know what to do:

Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

This is my sql query

```
INSERT
INTO
  `locations`(
    `unique_id`,
    `latitude`,
    `longitude`,
    `coordinates`,
  )
VALUES(
  'Y2UyMTA4N2',
  45.933191,
  15.316599,
  'GeomFromText(POINT(45.713958 14.209463))',
)
```

How should query look like for inserting point values?

**UPDATE**
my create table statement

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `locations` (
  `id_location` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `unique_id` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` DECIMAL(9,7) NULL,
  `longitude` DECIMAL(9,7) NULL,
  `coordinates` POINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_location`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `unique_id_UNIQUE` (`unique_id` ASC),
  SPATIAL INDEX `coordinates_idx` (`coordinates` ASC))
ENGINE = MyISAM
```

Comment: Please, post `SHOW CREATE TABLE \`locations\``.

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [13.15.3 Functions That Create Geometry Values from WKT
>   Values :: GeomFromText(wkt[, srid]), GeometryFromText(wkt[, srid])](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-wkt-functions.html#function_geomfromtext).
>
> ...
>
> GeomFromText() and GeometryFromText() are deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.6
>   and will be removed in a future MySQL release. Use ST_GeomFromText()
>   and ST_GeometryFromText() instead.

Try:

```sql
INSERT INTO `locations`
( `unique_id`,
  `latitude`,
  `longitude`,
  `coordinates`
) VALUES (
    'Y2UyMTA4N2',
    45.933191,
    15.316599,
    -- 'GeomFromText(POINT(45.713958 14.209463))' -- ERROR
    -- GeomFromText('POINT(45.713958 14.209463)')
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(45.713958 14.209463)')
);
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/79bH4oGDj7PKLLicBGsaQo/0).

Answer (score 1):

The text is - `POINT(45.713958 14.209463)`, `GeomFromText` is a function, so try this query -

```
INSERT
INTO
  `locations`(
    `unique_id`,
    `latitude`,
    `longitude`,
    `coordinates`
  )
VALUES(
  'Y2UyMTA4N2',
  45.933191,
  15.316599,
  GeomFromText('POINT(45.713958 14.209463)')
)
```